# Async Request with XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I need to write async Request to find according article in a search input.
I use API of Unplash.com and New York Times.
Code doesn't show any errors in dev tools. 
I've attached codepen link:

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ksena19/pen/vjPNvm)

```
(function(){
  const form = document.querySelector('#search-form');
  const searchField = document.querySelector('#search-keyword');
  let searchedForText;
  const responseContainer = document.querySelector('#response-container');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    responseContainer.innerHTML = '';

    function addArticles () {}

    function addImage() {}

   const imgRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   imgRequest.onload = addImage;
   imgRequest.onerror = function(err) {
     requestError(err, 'image');
   };
   imgRequest.open('GET', `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=${searchedForText}`);
   imgRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID <27182>');
   imgRequest.send();

   const articleRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   articleRequest.onload = addArticles;
   articleRequest.onerror = function (err) {
     requestError(err, 'articles');
   }
   articleRequest.open('GET', 
   `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json? 
   q=${searchedForText}&api-key=<4c32dbc91636470fb8e286e60041dca5>`);
   articleRequest.send();

  });
});
```

Comment: You need to execute the function too, not just define it. `(function(){ ... })();`

Comment: anyway, it's stil doesn't work

Comment: Just remove the invalid characters from your url : articleRequest.open('GET', 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=${searchedForText}&api-key=4c32dbc91636470fb8e286e60041dca5'); and it will work